# Compiling and running JUnit test suite

Tags: java, junit, compiler-errors

I've made a JUnit test suite but I'm failing to build and run it from the command line as opposed to just letting IntelliJ perform its magic. I've downloaded junit-4.12.jar and hamcrest-core-1.3.jar. I'm ideally looking for a "portable" solution, i.e. one where all the necessary parameters are in the command rather than in a path variable in a bash file somewhere.

I believe I can compile it fine with: `javac -cp /path/to/junit-4.12.jar:. TestSuite.java`. This produces a `TestSuite.class` file with no errors.

But I've tried every command I can find to run it and I always get errors. For example: `java -cp /path/to/junit-4.12.jar:/path/to/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:. org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TestSuite` gives:

```
JUnit version 4.12
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.junit.runner.Computer.getSuite(Computer.java:28)
    at org.junit.runner.Request.classes(Request.java:75)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.createRequest(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:118)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:77)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:36)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 17 more
```

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Comment: If you are running in Windows use `;` instead of `:`, to separate the jar files

Answer (score 0):

I think if you surround your classpath with double quotes and use semi-colon instead of colon for the delimiter, it should work:

```
java -cp "/path/to/junit-4.12.jar;/path/to/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;." org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TestSuite
```

If you still get the same error, then I think you just have a typo in your hamcrest path.